# MVC Model not being populated by database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, postgresql, nhibernate, model

I have a model that is mapped to an employee table in a postgres database. I'm using Nhibernate as my ORM instead of entity framework.

When I try to display the model's data in a view, it shows that the model is empty even though there are records in the table and the model should be populated.

Here is my model:

```
    public class Employee
    {

        [Key] public virtual int EmplID { get; set; }
        public virtual string EmpLastName { get; set; }
        public virtual string EmpFirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my table mappings:

```
public class EmpMap : ClassMapping<Employee>
{
    public EmpMap()
    {
        Table("tableName");
        Id(x => x.EmplID, x => x.Column("emp_id"));
        Property(x => x.EmpLastName, x => x.Column("emp_last"));
        Property(x => x.EmpFirstName, x => x.Column("emp_first"));
    }
}
```

Here is my controller where I attempt to populate the model:

```
  // GET: Employee
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        var emp = Database.Session.Query<Employee>().AsEnumerable();
        return View ("Index", emp);
    }
```

And here is my view where I attempt to display the data from the model:

```
@model IEnumerable<App_Catalog.Models.Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpLastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpFirstName)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpLastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpFirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
```

Comment: You should correct the `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpLastName)` but it is no the root cause of problem.

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint at the point it loads the data and checked if data is loading from the DB (ie ignore before it even gets to the view)?   "model is empty" - do you mean it's null or there are no records?  Try adding a `ToList()` to the DB query to force it to make the DB call before it goes to the view:  ` var emp = Database.Session.Query<Employee>().AsEnumerable().ToList();`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpLastName)` is fine. The method has an overload which accepts `IEnumarable<T>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I can't find a such overload. Can you please provide a link?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, The [second overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on NHibernate DEBUG logging and verify that the correct SQL query is being executed in the database.

Double-check that your program is really connecting to the correct database.

Problems with permissions, schema names, table names, column names etc should result in an exception being thrown, so unless you somewhere "handle" errors by sweeping them under the rug, such errors should reveal themselves clearly.

Check that your mapping class really applies to the correct entity class (in case you have multiple copies of similar classes) and also check that your mapping configuration is really being loaded into your session factory. (If it's not, you are querying an *unmapped* class, which is *not* an error, but will in fact return an empty list). If this is the case, you shouldn't see any SQL from this query in the NHibernate DEBUG log.

I'm uncertain how that AsEnumerable() is really implemented, and I haven't used if before. Replace it with ToList() to rule out any possible interference from that.

Comment: I forgot to add the mapping to my database configuration class, so you were right, I was querying an unmapped class. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

is your tables name - `tableName` ?

also it seems like here:

```
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpLastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpFirstName)
    </th>
</tr>
```

you are trying to call a property on the model, while your model is `IEnumerable<App_Catalog.Models.Employee>`

and there is a "`</tr> }`" missing at the end of your `foreach` loop. is that the way you copied your code, or is it an actual typo?

also... (sorry for so many edits).. you should use `model` instead of `Model` in your loop

Comment: No, that is just a placeholder for the actual name.

Comment: The "</tr>}" is actually in my code. I just did copy far enough down to include it in the posting. Sorry for the confusion!